# how do I organize a table in postgres sql in ascending order?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I would like to organize my postgresql table in ascending order from the date it was created on.
So I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM price
ORDER BY created_on;
```

And it did show me the database in that order, however it did not save it.

Is there a way I can make it so it gets saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables in a relational database represent **unordered** sets. There is no such thing as the "order of rows" in a table.

If you need a specific sort order, the only way is to use an `order by` in a select statement as you did.

If you don't want to type the `order by` each time, you can create a view that does that:

```
create view sorted_price
as
select *
from price
order by created_on;
```

But be warned: if you sort the rows from the view in a different way, e.g. `select * from sorted_price order by created_on desc` Postgres will actually apply two sorts. The query optimizer is unfortunately not smart enough to remove the one store in the view's definition.

Comment: As an optimisation, you can (a) create an index, although for listing the whole table it might not help much; or (b) CLUSTER the table, although that's a heavy operation and the order won't be maintained for new rows

Comment: So it created a new table... interesting... Thank you.

Comment: @pete: no, it's not a table. A view only stores the query, not data at all

Comment: @sabik: CLUSTER won't help as it will not guarantee any sort order. The **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `order by`. Without it the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes.

Comment: Yeah, CLUSTER is purely an optimisation, to potentially help the queries with ORDER BY run faster